# Javascript Breaks with Ajax Page Rendering

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a rails page, `show`, with two tabs, projects and members. When one of the tabs is clicked, the corresponding partial is rendered via AJAX. This all works great, except that when I render these pages through ajax, javascript functions don't appear to work with the content rendered.

For example, in the 'Members' tab, I have a link, 'Add User', that when clicked should change the CSS display property on certain divs from none to block. This does not function however. Any help would be much appreciated!

**show.html.erb**

```
<div id="collective_tabs">
  <%= link_to 'Projects', collective_projects_path(@collective), remote: true %>
  <%= link_to 'Members', collective_members_path(@collective), remote: true %>
</div>
<div id="collective_content">
    <%= render 'projects' %>
</div>
```

**members.js.erb**

```
$('#collective_content').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'members') %>");
```

**_members.html.erb**

```
<div id="collective_members">
    <div id="add_user"><%= link_to '(Add User)', '#' %></div>
    <div class="popup" id="pop_up_form">
        <div id="user_search_form">
            <%= render 'shared/user_search_form' %>
        </div>
        <div id="close_window"><%= link_to 'x', '#' %></div>
    </div>
    <div class="black_overlay" id="fade_overlay"></div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.black_overlay {
    display: none;
}
.popup {
    display: none;
}
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require chosen-jquery
//= require messages
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#add_user').click(function (event) {
      document.getElementById('pop_up_form').style.display='block'
      document.getElementById('fade_overlay').style.display='block'
      event.preventDefault(); // Prevent link from following its href
    });

    $('#close_window').click(function (event) {
      document.getElementById('pop_up_form').style.display='none'
      document.getElementById('fade_overlay').style.display='none'
      event.preventDefault(); // Prevent link from following its href
    });
});
```

Comment: `turbolinks` may be interfering with your code, as on a link click it causes only `<body>` replacement, not a full reload, and `ready` doesn't fire, which results in events not binding. Try fully reloading the page and checking if it works again.

Comment: Hmm yea, you're definitely right. I was concerned that turbolinks might be the problem. Is there any solution to this besides either removing the ajax?

Comment: Of course, it is in the [`turbolinks` docs](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#events) :) Bind to `$(document).on("page:load")` or an earlier event if necessary.